# Running Nginx and Drupal

Tags: nginx, drupal

I am new to Nginx but I managed to install Drupal on  windows 8 machine. I just noticed that this URL(http://localhost:8080/drupal/) spits out error message **403 Forbidden**. If I mutate that URL a bit by including the index(http://localhost:8080/drupal/index.php) file then it works as expected.  My question is this:
How could I configure Nginx so that I wont get error message when I go to http://localhost:8080/drupal/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, an `index` directive will encourage `nginx` to look for specific files when encountering a directory:

```
index index.php;
```

For a more specific rule, to single out that one path and map it to the controller, you could use an exact match `location` directive:

```
location = /drupal/ { rewrite ^ /drupal/index.php last; }
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.